# Implementing TLD on OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I am trying to implement a TLD real time tracker on OpenCV. I have googled but couldn't find any concise tutorials as to how to correctly implement the tracker. Please guide me as to how to do so.

Is there anyway to store the learned data to a data file or something like that so that next time the tracker is initialised, it reads the data from the configuration file and hence it is not necessary to draw bounding boxes around the object of interest every time?

I also wish to be able to detect multiple objects using TLD. Say the detector was first trained to detect cats and then cars. Assume that the detector saved the learned data to files cats.data and cars.data respectively. Is there anyway to initialise the tracker with both these config files so that it detects both the objects?

Comment: What not take ready implementation? http://www.gnebehay.com/tld/

Comment: Here is a Opencv Tutorial Code to perform AKAZE Tracking!https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/features2D/AKAZE_tracking/planar_tracking.cpp Default path is  sources\samples\cpp\tutorial_code\features2D\AKAZE_tracking\

Comment: Why not using the [TLD](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d1c/classcv_1_1TrackerTLD.html#gsc.tab=0) **already implemented** in OpenCV?

Comment: @Miki can you please point me to some resource that shows a step by step process of how to implement it?

Comment: [OpenCV github](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/tracking/src) or as already stated in the comments [OpenTLD](https://github.com/zk00006/OpenTLD)